# normal vector stokes theorem calculation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

$$\int\int_S (\nabla \times F) \cdot n \, dS$$

Solving Stokes' theorem using Curl form, I'm having an issue with the calculation of the normal vector when using parameterization of the surface and a cross product vs. $f(x,y,z)=z-g(x,y)$ form.

Curl is given as $\langle-2z, -2x, -2y\rangle$ and C as the intersection of $z=\sqrt{5-x^2 -y^2}$ and $z=1$

Parameterizing results in $r(x,y)=\langle x, y, 1\rangle$. The cross product of the partial with respect to x and y gives a normal vector of $\langle 0,0,1 \rangle$

However if I want to use the form $z-g(x,y)$ with $z=\sqrt{5-x^2 -y^2} $
it is not evident to me how I get to the same normal vector after taking the gradient. I get $\left\langle \frac{x}{\sqrt{5-x^2 -y^2}}，\frac{y}{\sqrt{5-x^2 -y^2}}, 1 \right\rangle$

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the open surface $S$?  Is it the surface $z=\sqrt{5-x^2-z^2}$, $z\in [0,1]$?  Or is it the surface $z=\sqrt{5-x^2-z^2}$, $z\in [1,\sqrt 5]$?

Comment: Not sure I understand fully. In the question C was just described as the intersection of the two surfaces given above. My understanding of Stoke’s is that the result is only dependent on C and independent on the actual (bounded) surface as long as the boundary is C. But as far as open surface that’s all that was given

Comment: Your question regards the calculation of the unit normal of a surface.  The contour $C$ bounds many surfaces.

Comment: Thanks, so in application what changes in order to equate to the same answer? The limits of integration seem to be set since we will still be integrating over the same boundary.